# Eclipse - Adding Java 'Application Run' Shortcuts to toolbar

Tags: shortcuts, eclipse

In Eclipse (I'm using 3.4.1) you can create "favourite" run configurations. These simply appear fixed at the top of the list of Run configurations.

[image]

Is there a way to create a shortcut to a runtime launcher in the Eclipse toolbar itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to do this is to code it your self, which is why I never have.  I think you have to subclass ControlContribution (org.eclipse.jface) and implement createControl(Composite).  It's possible the [RCP Book](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/RCP_Book) provides a cookbook solution to this problem as it's often asked.

It's possible you could hack an existing plugin menu, but I'm not really sure you want to go there either.

Comment: I had a feeling that this would be the case. I'll give it a couple of days before marking as correct though... (just in case)